# From multiline heredocument to a uniline herestring, with line breaks

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document, syntax, here-string

I have this multilinie heredocument which I desire to translate into a uniline herestring:

```
cat <<-"PHPCONF" > /etc/php/*/zz_overrides.ini
  [PHP]
  post_max_size = 200M
  upload_max_filesize = 200M
  cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0
PHPCONF
```

The closest I could get is as follows:

```
cat >"/etc/php/*/zz_overrides.ini" <<< "[PHP] post_max_size = 200M upload_max_filesize = 200M cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0"
```

but I don't think **line breaks** after each directive is possible, given the end result is one **string**. Maybe there is some "unorthodox" way after all?

---

Both the heredoc, and herestring, are aimed to replace this heavy sed operation:

```
sed -i "s/post_max_size = .M/post_max_size = 200M/ ; s/upload_max_filesize = .M/upload_max_filesize = 200M/ ; s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/" /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
```

Comment: Um, I may be misunderstanding here - but can't you just use `printf`? e.g. `printf '  [PHP]\n  post_max_size = 200M\n  upload_max_filesize = 200M\n  cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0\n'`

Comment: I used heredocument/herestring to create the file on the way, but `touch` + `&&` may be handy, because AFAIK, one cannot create a file with `printf`.

Comment: Huh? you can *redirect* the `printf` output to a file (which will create it if it doesn't exist)

Comment: Oh, sure, I didn't think of that, I'm quite new to redirections and I need to internalize this concept better. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `cat` doesn't create files either.  The *redirection* that you use creates the file.

Comment: How will you define what `cat` does? If it was `bash` instead cache the code was executed but what `cat` is "concatenating" in this particular case? Only the streams one to another?

Comment: @pntshere, `cat` just opens all files listed on its command line, reads them, and writes them to its standard output. It doesn't open any files for writing itself. An output redirection makes the shell create them if necessary. That also happens without `cat`: you could write `true > some.file` and the file is created. The concatenation bit comes if you give more than one input for `cat`. It doesn't separate them in its output, so you get a concatenation. but with just one input, there's really nothing to concatenate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that you could just `printf "this\nthat\n" > /some/file`, you can make a here-string with newlines with e.g. ANSI-C quoting:

```
$ cat <<< $'this\nthat'
this
that
```

Also, because of the quotes, this will try to create a file in a directory literally named `*`:

```
cat > "/etc/php/*/zz_overrides.ini"
```

This would work in Bash, but only if the glob matches one file (if you have `/etc/php/foo/zz_overrides.ini` and `/etc/php/bar/zz_overrides.ini`, Bash gives an error)

```
cat > /etc/php/*/zz_overrides.ini
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `bash` allow you to use a string with newlines directly, no need for a heredoc, or calling external commands (like `cat`):

```
$ php_conf='
  [PHP]
  post_max_size = 200M
  upload_max_filesize = 200M
  cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0
'

$ echo "$php_conf"

 [PHP]
 post_max_size = 200M
 upload_max_filesize = 200M
 cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0
```